# business rule engine

Tags: php, rules, high-availability, business-rules, rule-engine

We have several applications in different programming languages we use Oracle and MySQL as storage. Most business logic is stored inside code and Oracle procedures. Now it becomes a big(ger) problem every time we have to implement new features with new rules.

Because:

1. It's hard to implement the business rules correctly in different languages without any mistake...
2. It's time consuming.
3. Hard to test.
4. Code becomes messy every time there is a change (although we do allot of refactoring we cannot keep it clean enough (we have releases every 2 weeks))

Now I heard of the existence of a business rule engine (BRE) to process the business rules (BR). It would be great if the PHP application (high traffic e-commerce website) can perform a request to the BRE and get a JSON response. It would be even greater if we can use old rules to perform historic checks. The C# application should also use the BRE.

For the more experienced people what are your thoughts about this?

Comment: Voting to migrate this question to [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) since it's about software design rather than a specific coding issue.

Comment: Jürgen you are probably right can move it myself?

Comment: No, this would be cross posting and is frowned upon, afaik. But you can flag your question to get a moderator's attention and ask him/her to migrate it for you.